# Clojure - Sliding Window Minimum in Log Time

Tags: clojure, sliding-window

Given vector size n and window size k, how can I efficiently calculate the sliding window minimum in n log k time?  ie, for vector [1 4 3 2 5 4 2] and window size 2, the output would be [1 3 2 2 4 2].

Obviously I can do it using partition and map but that that's n * k time.

I think I need to keep track of the minimum in a sorted map, and update the map when it's outside the window.  But although I can get the min of a sorted map in log time, searching through the map to find any indexes that are expired is not log time.

Thanks.

Comment: This seems more like an algorithms question than a Clojure question. If you have an algorithm in mind, someone can help with implementing it in Clojure. But as is, this is sorta a "help me solve an interview problem" sort of thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve this is with a priority queue based on [Clojure's priority map](https://github.com/clojure/data.priority-map) data structure. We index the values in the window with their position in the vector.

- The value of its first entry is the window minimum.
- We add the new entry and get rid of the oldest one by key/vector-position.

A possible implementation is

```
(use [clojure.data.priority-map :only [priority-map]])

(defn windowed-min [k coll]
  (let [numbered (map-indexed list coll)
        [head tail] (split-at k numbered)
        init-win (into (priority-map) head)
        win-seq (reductions
                  (fn [w [i n]]
                    (-> w (dissoc (- i k)) (assoc i n)))
                  init-win
                  tail)]
    (map (comp val first) win-seq)))
```

For example,

```
(windowed-min 2 [1 4 3 2 5 4 2])
=> (1 3 2 2 4 2)
```

The solution is developed lazily, so can be applied to an endless sequence.

---

After the initialisation, which is *O(k)*, the function computes each element in the sequence in *O(log k)* time, as noted [here](https://github.com/clojure/data.priority-map/blob/master/src/main/clojure/clojure/data/priority_map.clj).

Comment: "After the initialisation, which is O(k) […]" deserves an upvote.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's a great solution.  I ended up hacking together a solution of my own runs faster, but I think that's due to it being eager.

Comment: Initialization is also O(k*log k) since (into (priority-map) head) equates to (reduce conj (priority-map) head) which is [William's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap).  Priority-map doesn't appear to provide [Floyd's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap) which would be O(k) to build the priority-map.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve in linear time --O(n), rather than O(n*log k)) as described by 1. http://articles.leetcode.com/sliding-window-maximum/ (easily change from find max to find min) and 2. https://people.cs.uct.ac.za/~ksmith/articles/sliding_window_minimum.html

The approaches needs a double ended queue to manage previous values which uses O(1) time for most queue operations (i.e. push/pop/peek, etc.) rather than O(log K) when using Priority Queue (i.e. Priority Map).  I used a double ended queue from https://github.com/pjstadig/deque-clojure

Main Code to implement code in 1st reference above (for min rather than max):

```
(defn windowed-min-queue [w a]
  (let [
        deque-init (fn deque-init [] (reduce (fn [dq i]
                                               (dq-push-back i (prune-back a i dq)))
                                             empty-deque (range w)))

        process-min (fn process-min [dq] (reductions (fn [q i]
                                                       (->> q
                                                            (prune-back a i)
                                                            (prune-front i w)
                                                            (dq-push-back i)))
                                                     dq (range w (count a))))
        init (deque-init)
        result (process-min init)] ;(process-min init)]
    (map #(nth a (dq-front %)) result)))
```

Comparing the speed of this method to the other solution that uses a Priority Map we have (note: I liked the other solution since as well since its simpler).

```
; Test using Random arrays of data
(def N 1000000)
(def a (into [] (take N (repeatedly #(rand-int 50)))))
(def b (into [] (take N (repeatedly #(rand-int 50)))))
(def w 1024)
; Solution based upon Priority Map (see other solution which is also great since its simpler)
(time (doall (windowed-min-queue w a)))
;=> "Elapsed time: 1820.526521 msecs"
; Solution based upon  double-ended queue
(time (doall (windowed-min w b)))
;=> "Elapsed time: 8290.671121 msecs"
```

Which is over a 4x faster, which is great considering the PriorityMap is written in Java while the double-ended queue code is pure Clojure (see https://github.com/pjstadig/deque-clojure)

Including the other wrappers/utilities used on the double-ended queue for reference.

```
(defn dq-push-front [e dq]
  (conj dq e))

(defn dq-push-back [e dq]
  (proto/inject dq e))

(defn dq-front [dq]
  (first dq))

(defn dq-pop-front [dq]
  (pop dq))

(defn dq-pop-back [dq]
  (proto/eject dq))

(defn deque-empty? [dq]
  (identical? empty-deque dq))

(defn dq-back [dq]
  (proto/last dq))

(defn dq-front [dq]
  (first dq))

(defn prune-back [a i dq]
  (cond
    (deque-empty? dq) dq
    (< (nth a i) (nth a (dq-back dq))) (recur a i (dq-pop-back dq))
    :else dq))

(defn prune-front [i w dq]
  (cond
    (deque-empty? dq) dq
    (<= (dq-front dq) (- i w)) (recur i w (dq-pop-front dq))
    :else dq))
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution uses two auxillary maps to achieve fast performance.  I map the keys to their values and also store the values to their occurrences in a sorted map.  Upon each move of the window, I update the maps, and get the minimum of the sorted map, all in log time.

The downside is the code is a lot uglier, not lazy, and not idiomatic.  The upside is that it outperforms the priority-map solution by about 2x.  I think a lot of that though, can be blamed on the laziness of the solution above.

```
(defn- init-aux-maps [w v]
  (let [sv (subvec v 0 w)
        km (->> sv (map-indexed vector) (into (sorted-map)))
        vm (->> sv frequencies (into (sorted-map)))]
    [km vm]))

(defn- update-aux-maps [[km vm] j x]
  (let [[ai av] (first km)
        km (-> km (dissoc ai) (assoc j x))
        vm (if (= (vm av) 1) (dissoc vm av) (update vm av dec))
        vm (if (nil? (get vm x)) (assoc vm x 1) (update vm x inc))]
    [km vm]))

(defn- get-minimum [[_ vm]] (ffirst vm))

(defn sliding-minimum [w v]
  (loop [i 0, j w, am (init-aux-maps w v), acc []]
    (let [acc (conj acc (get-minimum am))]
      (if (< j (count v))
        (recur (inc i) (inc j) (update-aux-maps am j (v j)) acc)
        acc))))
```